# TreeView.insert throws UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: windows, python-2.7, utf-8, treeview

I'm trying to populate TreeView with data from os.listdir(path).

All is ok until I read a directory name with a non-utf character. In my case 0xf6 which is not utf8.

As I'm running on Windows the charset from os.listdir() is Windows-1252 or ANSI.

How can I solve this problem to achieve correct display in TreeView?

Here some of my code:

```
def fill_tree(treeview, node):
    if treeview.set(node, "type") != 'directory':
        return

    path = treeview.set(node, "fullpath")
    # Delete the possibly 'dummy' node present.
    treeview.delete(*treeview.get_children(node))

    parent = treeview.parent(node)
    for p in os.listdir(path):
        ptype = None
        p = os.path.join(path, p)

        if os.path.isdir(p):
            ptype = 'directory'

        fname = os.path.split(p)[1].decode('cp1252').encode('utf8')

        if ptype == 'directory':
            oid = treeview.insert(node, 'end', text=fname, values=[p, ptype])
            treeview.insert(oid, 0, text='dummy')
```

Regards
Göran

Comment: There are many matches for "treeview" on PyPi. Which library are you using specifically? And: what type are the offending dictionary keys, `str` or `unicode`?

Comment: I'm using Tkinter. Don't understand your question on 'offending dictonary keys'?

Comment: O sorry, I did'nt read carefully. I meant "directory name". But I'm pretty sure `os.listdir()` returns `str`, not `unicode`. You can decode the directory name using `name.decode('cp1252')`, which gives you a Unicode string. Then check if TreeView.insert accepts this.

Comment: I tried name.decode('cp1252').encode('utf8') and it works fine. But I get into trouble when I continue looping through the directory tree - os.path.isdir(p) does not work as desired with utf encoding? Catch-22 situation?

Comment: Sounds like you need to keep to separate variables: the CP-1252 version for `os.*` and the UTF-8 version for the TreeView. Or you switch to Python 3, where everything should work with Unicode strings.

Comment: Added a code snippet to show my problem.

Comment: os.listdir(unicode(path)) made this work as expected! Thank you for all assistance. /Göran

Answer (score 0):

The `UnicodeDecodeError` is due to passing byte strings when the function is expecting Unicode strings.  Python 2 attempts to implicitly decode byte strings to Unicode.  Use Unicode strings explicitly instead.  `os.listdir(unicode_path)` will return Unicode string, for example `os.listdir(u'.')`.